# Asymptotic OLS estimates

Tags: least-squares

In simple (univariate) OLS $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$, the estimate of the slope coefficient is asymptotically equal to the ratio of covariances, i.e. 
$$
\hat{\beta_1} \rightarrow \frac{Cov[X,Y]}{Cov[X,X]}
$$ 
so if we know what the covariance matrix for the joint distribution of $[X,Y]$ is we can derive OLS coefficients without needing any data.

Can we do the same for the multivariate case? For example, if we know the covariance matrix of the data-generating process for $[Y,X_1,X_2]$, what would be the asymptotic expression for OLS coefficients in $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2$?

**Add 1**
If the data was centered (or the means where zero) then the data matrix $\textbf{X}^T\textbf{X}$ (without column of 1s) would asymptotically be equal to the co-variance matrix of $[X_1,X_2]$. But the estimate includes the column of 1s and work with non-centered data, so it's not clear to me what this becomes in this case.

**Add 2**
If do apply the OLS formula for **zero-mean RVs without adding the column of 1s** to the data matrix, then for 2 explanatory variables we get
$$
\textbf{X}^T \textbf{X} =  
    \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} \\
    x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} \\
    \vdots & \vdots \\
    x_{n,1} & x_{n,2}\\
    \end{bmatrix}^T
    \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} \\
    x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} \\
    \vdots & \vdots \\
    x_{n,1} & x_{n,2}\\
    \end{bmatrix}
=
    \begin{bmatrix}
   \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,1}^2 & \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,1}x_{i,2} \\
   \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,1}x_{i,2} & \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,2}^2 \\
       \end{bmatrix}
$$
and its inverse is 
$$
(\textbf{X}^T \textbf{X})^{-1} = \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,1}^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,2}^2 - (\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,1}x_{i,2})^2}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,2}^2 & -\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,1}x_{i,2} \\
   -\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,1}x_{i,2} & \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,1}^2 \\
   \end{bmatrix}
$$
The other term is given by
$$
\textbf{X}^T \textbf{y} =  
    \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} \\
    x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} \\
    \vdots & \vdots \\
    x_{n,1} & x_{n,2}\\
    \end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix}
    y_{1} \\
    y_{2} \\
    \vdots \\
    y_{n} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
=
    \begin{bmatrix}
   \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,1}y_{i} \\
   \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,2}y_{i}  \\
       \end{bmatrix}
$$
Putting it together gives
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \hat{\beta}_{1} \\
    \hat{\beta}_{2} \\
    \end{bmatrix} =
(\textbf{X}^T \textbf{X})^{-1} \textbf{X}^T \textbf{y}
=  \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,1}^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,2}^2 - (\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,1}x_{i,2})^2}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,2}^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,1}y_{i} -\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,1}x_{i,2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,2}y_{i} \\
   \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,1}^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,2}y_{i} -\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,1}x_{i,2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,1}y_{i} \\
   \end{bmatrix}
$$
which seems to agree with the result in the OP of the question pointed to by whuber.
Asymptotically, this looks like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \hat{\beta}_{1} \\
    \hat{\beta}_{2} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow (Cov(\textbf{X},\textbf{X}))^{-1} Cov(\textbf{X},Y)
$$
where $\textbf{X}$ now indicates a multivariate RV, not the data matirx of observations.
Since covariances do not depend on means, I believe that this result also holds for non-zero mean RVs.

Comment: Re the edit: it's unclear where you're going with this, because the estimates are the same whether or not the columns of $X$ are centered provided only that the span of the columns includes the constant vector.  The asymptotic distribution doesn't know or care how you go about actually computing the estimates!

Comment: @whuber Thank you for you comment and for pointing me to the other post. On where I was going with the edit: I thought that maybe the generalization can be expressed as "the ratio" of covariance matricies, i.e. $(Cov[\textbf{X},\textbf{X}])^{-1}(Cov[\textbf{X},Y])$ that is the inverse of covariance matrix of Xs times the covariance matrix of Xs with Y.